# Coffeescript + Express: unexpected ,

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript

I'm learning to make an app on Express.js using Coffeescript. I have uploaded my code at: https://github.com/findjashua/contactlist

When I try to run the app, I get the following error:

```
app.coffee:11:24: error: unexpected ,
res.send 'Hello World'
                   ^
```

I don't understand the issue here. Any ideas?

Comment: I have no clue. It can’t run, but compiles just fine. You might want to file a bug.

Comment: The issue was in contacts.coffee, no idea why the compiler was pointing to app.coffee

Comment: Yep, that’s a source mapping bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On line 11 in contacts.coffee you have

```
exports.index = (req, res) ->
  ContactModel.find (err, contacts), ->
    if not err
```

remove that comma on the central line, after `contacts)`.